# PHP has strange output in zsh

Tags: php, bash, zsh

I'm trying to run this code in zsh and bash

index.php

```php
<?php
echo "Str1";
echo "Str2\n";
echo "Str3";
?>
```

bash gives me this

```
[...]$ php index.php
Str1Str2
Str3[...]$
```

but zsh has strange output, it doesn't print the last line

```
[...]$ php index.php
Str1Str2
[...]$
```

Is it some bug of zsh?

Comment: Suppose to be the same: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol#:~:text=And%20by%20default%20zsh%20goes%20to%20the%20next,a%20normal%20user%20or%20a%20%22%23%22%20for%20root.

Comment: The final newline is missing after Str3. Technically speaking, the command is incomplete. You can set in zsh the variable i.e. `PROMPT_EOL_MARK='<???>'`, so that these cases are better to see. Actually, I have set my eol-mark to `⁇` (Unicode 2047) and found this pretty distinguishing and easy to see.